# Can 23/32 advancetech subflooring be installed over 3/4 wood plank subfloor?

Tags: flooring, underlayment, vinyl

We are working on laying vinyl plank flooring. After getting the carpet up, we found that the subfloor was particle board with glue stuck all over it, so we decided to rip it up and go with 23/32 AdvanceTech. After removing the particle board there 3/4" x 5-1/2" (actual size) wood planks running across the joists at a 45° angle.

I'd like to leave the planks on the joists and screw the AdvanceTech down over the planks. Does anyone see an issue with this?

Comment: If the planks are solid and flat(test with a long straight edge) then should be good.  Follow the instructions for the flooring.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. When you took the [tour], you should have noted that we like to work on a "one-question-per-question" basis here, so your "Also..." question makes this a bit too broad. You're free to ask that as a second, stand-alone question, however, the answer will be "what do the directions with _your_ flooring say?"

Comment: Thats my bad, FreeMan. I was at working while reading through the tour and must have missed that segment. Thanks for the comment, i edited my question to resolve the issue.